How to keep standard port such as 80 443 in Host header NGINX Ingress Controller
I am deploy a MinIO with Kubernetes and NGINX ingress controller. MinIO API need to know port existed in 'Host' header to calculate signature. For testing, I run NGINX ingress controller in 1 worker node.
dotnet-client ===> Nginx Ingress controller ===> MinIO deployment

This is my request that dotnet-client send to MinIO API that contain :80 in Host header:
- - - - - - - - - - BEGIN REQUEST - - - - - - - - - -

GET http://minio.vobaitap.online/ HTTP/1.1
Host: minio.vobaitap.online:80
x-amz-content-sha256: ***
x-amz-date: 20240817T074728Z
Authorization: ***, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, ***

- - - - - - - - - - END REQUEST - - - - - - - - - -

I used tcpdump to catch HTTP request. tcpdump result show that worker server receive request contain ':80' in Host header.
enter image description here
But when I trace my MinIO deployment, result shows that value of Host header was exclude :80, so that my request was blocked:
minio.vobaitap.online [REQUEST s3.ListBuckets] [2024-08-17T14:47:39.854] [Client IP: 118.70.99.75]
minio.vobaitap.online GET /
minio.vobaitap.online Proto: HTTP/1.1
minio.vobaitap.online Host: minio.vobaitap.online
minio.vobaitap.online Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
minio.vobaitap.online User-Agent: MinIO (Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631;X64) minio-dotnet/1.0.9
minio.vobaitap.online X-Real-Ip: 118.70.99.75
minio.vobaitap.online Authorization: ***, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=***
minio.vobaitap.online X-Forwarded-For: 118.70.99.75
minio.vobaitap.online X-Forwarded-Host: minio.vobaitap.online
minio.vobaitap.online Accept: application/json, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, application/xml, text/xml
minio.vobaitap.online Traceparent: ***
minio.vobaitap.online X-Amz-Date: 20240817T074728Z
minio.vobaitap.online X-Forwarded-Port: 80
minio.vobaitap.online X-Forwarded-Proto: http
minio.vobaitap.online Connection: close
minio.vobaitap.online Content-Length: 0
minio.vobaitap.online X-Amz-Content-Sha256: ***

My ingress configuration:
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: minio-ingress
  namespace: minio
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: minio.vobaitap.online
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: minio-service
                port:
                  number: 9000

I've tried with annotation nginx.org/proxy-set-headers according Proxy-Set-Headers Annotation example   but MinIO API return error "mc.exe:  Unable to listen to http trace. Failed to parse server response (unexpected end of JSON input):."
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: minio-ingress
  namespace: minio
  annotations:
    nginx.org/proxy-set-headers: "Host"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
...

Nginx Ingress version: 3.6.1
Kubernetes version: 1.29.6
minio-dotnet: 1.0.9 (from NuGet pagkage MinIO 3.1.13)
How can I keep ':80' in Host header ?

nginx will strip up default port 80 and 443 from host header,therefore try using non default port like 8080 or 8888 for MinIO.
if you have to preserve prot 80 in host header then use
'nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet' annotaions as follows:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minio-ingress
  namespace: minio
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: minio.vobaitap.online
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: minio-service
                port:
                  number: 9000

above settings comes with security implications you need to craft your own mesures.

Thank you about your help !
Your suggestion looks like belong to Ingress-Nginx Controller. But our system is using NGINX Ingress Controller.
Could you give some suggestions for my case ?

@NguyenVanDai if you using nginx ingress controller from nignx.org use ConfigMap

@NguyenVanDai did you create ConfigMap and deployed it like this:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
name: minio-proxy-headers
namespace: minio
data:
Host: "minio.vobaitap.online:80"

Oh sorry.
I've try ConfigMap but MinIO alway return 400 bad request.
I've try http-snippets, server-snippets, location-snippets but my MinIO API does not work.
I think there are some syntax problem at my config but I still can't find them.
My syntax:

kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
name: nginx-config
namespace: nginx-ingress
data:
http-snippets: |
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

